# BLFS 8.2, SDDM (from BLFS 8.1) shows password as boxes instead of circles

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-5

I have just finished installing KDE Plasma 5 on my Linux From Scratch 8.2 system according to instructions from the BLFS 8.2 book. I have also installed SDDM as display manager according to BLFS 8.1, because it is not present in version 8.2. The login functionallity works fine, but the password is displayed as boxes/rectangles instead of circles/stars. Could it be caused by some font missing or is it some configuration issue? I have installed the Xorg fonts, the Oxygen fonts and the Noto Sans and Noto Sans Symbols fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved this problem by myself, the missing fonts were the DejaVu fonts, which aren't a dependency of any of the programs, which I installed, but they are strongly recommended to install according to their own section of the BLFS book.